# Variable amount with stripe elements

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I would like to create a payment page using stripe elements, based on this example

[image: example]

As you can see, they use Stripe elements, and the customer form is on the same page.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Your question needs more details.  Stripe has [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) on how to build a custom form.  We need to see your code segment and understand what specific problem you're having with your custom form.  We do not need to see pictures of your form.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow an example [like this](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/using-webhooks/server/php-slim/index.php), but when [creating the payment intent](https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment/blob/master/using-webhooks/server/php-slim/index.php#L47-L59) replace the calculation of `amount` based on items to just be an amount sent from the client on the `body`:

```
// Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
$payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  "amount" => $body->amount_entered,
  "currency" => $body->currency
]);
```